# How do I put all the text after the name of my command and the prefix into a variable like rest_of_message in the async def?

Tags: discord.py

So I'm making an afk command, and I want to store everything I type after !afk into the reason, instead of having to put "" around it. Is there any way I can do this? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text after the command is passed on as all variables in your program you can get all of those with `*args` and merge them back into a sentence with `' '.join(args)`.

Example code:

```
bot.command()
async def afk(ctx, *args):
    reason = ' '.join(args)
    ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name} has gone afk with the following reason: "{reason}", bye')
```

Comment: when i do this, it puts a space between each letter... is there any way to fix that? nvm i fixed